# HTML href how not to highlight

Tags: html

in this HTML tag I would like to have the word "or" not highlighted.

how can you do this?

```
<p>To ensure that you continue receiving our emails, <a href="mailto: my@email.com">please add us to your address book or safe list.</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why complicate things, use two mailto links.

```
 To ensure that you continue receiving our emails, 
 <a href="mailto: my@email.com">please add us to your address book</a>
 or 
 <a href="mailto: my@email.com">safe list.</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that you got your answer but I think this code will help you more:

```
    <style type="text/css">
            .EMail_Link:hover
            {
                    background: yellow;
                    color: black;
            }
            .EMail_Link:active
            {
                    color: red;
            }
    </style>
    <label>
    To ensure that you continue receiving our emails, 
    <a href="mailto: my@email.com" class="EMail_Link">please add us to your address book</a>
    or
    <a href="mailto: my@email.com" class="EMail_Link">safe list</a>.
    </label>
```

`<label>` will change the cursor from IBeam to Arrow when you hover the text.
`class="EMail_Link"` will change link style.

Answer (score 0):

Normal text will never be highlighted if you don't markup accordingly. So you need to markup all parts of the sentence to get highlighted.